# why doesnt my program work as it should? (why does it stop in the middle)

Tags: python, function, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

so my assigment was:

> Post of Slovenia often gets a letter with unreadable ZIP code because people write such a way that some of the figures difficult to read.
>
> Especially frequently make replacement
>
> - Between 3 to 8 ,
> - MED 1, 4 , 7, and 5
> - Between 6
>
> inscriptions subroutine Variants (k), which adopts a four-digit postcode K on the screen lists all the possible postcode can be obtained with these swaps digits. On the coating Variants (1035) on the screen appears the following zip codes, not necessarily against the order clean: 1035 , 1036 , 1085 , 1086 , 4035 , 4036 , 4085 , 4086 , 7035, 7036 , 7085 , 7086th

The python:

```
def versions (k):
    def Variante(x):
       a=['3', '8'] #prva tabela
       b=['1', '4', '7'] #druga tabela
       c=['5', '6'] #treta tabela
       v=[] #mozne variante
       x=[x]
       for s in x:
          if s==a[1] or s==a[0]: #ce je stevilka(s) u prvih tabeli
             v.append(a) 
          elif s==b[0] or s==[1] or s==[2]:#ce je stevilka(s) u drugi tabeli
             v.append(b)
          elif s==c[0] or c==[1]:#ce je stevilka(s) u treti tbabeli
             v.append(c)
          else:#ce stevilka(s) ni u nobeni skupini
             v.append(x)

       d=0
       while d<len(v[0]):
          e=0
          print ("ratal")
          while e<len(v[1]):
             f=0
             while f<len(v[2]):
                g=0
                while g<len(v[3]):
                   print(v[0][d], v[1][e], v[2][f], v[3][g])
                   g=g+1
                f=f+1
             e=e+1
          d=d+1

x=input("vnesi postno stevilko: ")
Variante(x)
```

Comment: Start by using meaningful variable names, not `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. This isn't BASIC from the 1960's, you're allow to use full words as variables.

Comment: Use print or logging statements to understand what's happening. And have a look at ipdb to add a breakpoint to your code. Then you can inspect variables, move step-by-step, etc. It's very helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're mapping a single character to *aliases*, you can think of this as getting the **cartesian product** of a list of aliases

http://repl.it/dgM/7

```
from itertools import product

def Variante(zip_code):
    replace_tables = [
        ['3', '8'], #prva tabela
        ['1', '4', '7'], #druga tabela
        ['5', '6'], #treta tabela
    ]

    # Convert to list of individual aliases
    aliased_chars = []
    for char in zip_code:
        aliased = False
        for table in replace_tables:
            if char in table:
                # Convert to possible aliases to this char
                aliased_chars.append(table)
                aliased = True
                break

        if not aliased:
            # Otherwise convert to list for itertools.product
            aliased_chars.append([char])

    # Get the cartesian product of lists
    return ["".join(l) for l in product(*aliased_chars)]

# x=input("vnesi postno stevilko: ")
print(Variante("1035"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...but can i ask why do you make a cartesian product of lists? and how exactly dos the #cinvert to list of individuač ačoases work. i really appreciate your help! @tommes

Comment: Hi, happy to help :-) The `aliased_chars` list is a list of possible characters on each position in the string, ie: `["3", "2"] -> [["3", "8"], ["2"]]`
The cartesian product can be defined as all possible combinations of a list of choices, eg: `[["1"], ["2", "7"]] -> [["1", "2], ["1", "7"]]`
I suggest watching this video on cartesian products: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4j4XgVbuxc&t=58

Comment: Try if this version using list comprehensions is more guiding: http://repl.it/dgM/9

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you mess up the indexing.  So,  for example, you have `s==[1]` instead of `s==b[1]`, and `c==[1]` instead of `s==c[1]`.

However, the area also other issues, although they are not errors. Instead of checking each value individually, you can do something like `s in b`.  And you can use `for` to loop over elements of a list directly instead of `while` looping over indexes. A more idiomatic version of your code would be this:

```
for s in x: 
    if s in a:
        v.append(a)
    elif s in b:
        v.append(b)
    elif s in c: 
        v.append(c)
    else:
        v.append(x)

for vd in v[0]:
    print("ratal")
    for ve in v[1]:
        for vf in v[2]:
          for vg in v[3]:
              print(vd, vem vf, vg)
```